How to extract distinct values of array field of embedded documents
Quick disclaimer that I am new to MongoDB.
So, I have a collection called 'Films' where documents have the following structure:
_id: ObjectID('6651be669853a31636ac8f5e') 
adult: "False"
original_language: "en"
genres: "[{'id': 68, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 21, 'name': 'War'}]"
...

I am interested in the genres field, which is an array of embedded documents, where each has an 'id' and a 'name' field. Note, that there can be more genres than 2. I want to get a list of all the distinct genre names in my Films collection. Based on similar questions I found online, I figured I have to use an aggregation pipeline, so I tried the following: (I am using Python in Sublime Text):
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi

uri = "..."
client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))
db = client['FilmDB']

pipeline = [
    {"$unwind": "$genres"},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$genres.name"}},
    {"$project": {"_id": 0, "name": "$_id"}}
]

distinct_genres_cursor = db["Films"].aggregate(pipeline)
distinct_genres = [genre['name'] for genre in distinct_genres_cursor]

print(distinct_genres)

However, I get [None]as output. I have tried a couple of different but similar methods, and I keep getting an empty list for distinct_genres.
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

is your genres stringified json

I am not sure, how would I check that? When I look at MongoDB, it says 'string' next to my genres.

unfortunately then you may have done somthing wrong when inserting. for you to do queries it has to be subdocument not string

https://mongoplayground.net/p/dRNlF5w3197 here is your query with subdocs. https://mongoplayground.net/p/2iBkztaSDs0 here as a string

If I run the one where it is a string, I get 'name' : null. So, the problem is that I somehow inserted my data wrong, and it should have been inserted as subdocs, instead of strings? I executed queries on this collection before, and that worked, but maybe it is the nature of the query (there I was checking if specific tokens appeared anywhere in the collection).

yes it seems like you are inserting json string for the genre. you may have to deserealize

Okay, so I can 'fix' the issue, without having to re-insert everything by deserializing? And to deserialize, I would just do: EJSON.deserialize( genres, [ options ] )? Do I need to choose a certain option? And can this just be done in my Python script? Sorry for the many questions and thanks for your help!

hmm if you want to query directly from the db youll have to have them in subdoc form at db level itself

As pointed out in the comments, you should probably fix the data source to make the data injected in proper json objects instead of strings.
Meanwhile, a no-so-elegant workaround would be using $function to parse the json string and convert it into json objects in an aggregation pipeline.
Note:

$function may introduce performance decrease
parsing the json string could be error-prone

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "genres": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$genres",
          "find": "'",
          "replacement": "\""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "genres": {
        "$function": {
          body: "function(genres) {return JSON.parse(genres)}",
          args: [
            "$genres"
          ],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$genres"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$genres.name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "$_id"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thanks for your help but unfortunately I get the error: NameError: name 'body' is not defined. I guess I'll just have to try and get my data in the right format..
